# construct or clean names for SQL filter using Notepad++ or Excel

Tags: sql, excel, notepad++

I frequently get excel files with 1000 company names that i need to match in our system to get their Internal ID's and other metrics, is there a easy way to do this cleaning

**my sample initial list**

```
Dash Network Inc.
Presto LLC
Blue origin, Inc.
```

**I need the output like this, So that i can execute in the Database**

```
UPPER(CMP_NM) LIKE 'DASH%NETWORK%'
OR UPPER(CMP_NM) LIKE 'PRESTO%'
OR UPPER(CMP_NM) LIKE 'BLUE%ORIGIN%'
```

I perform following steps, as such is there any easy way for this please.

```
(1) convert the list to upper
(2) remove INC or LLC
(3) find and replace spaces with %
(4) find in regular expression (.+) and replace with '\1%' --> for before and after single quotes with %
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two layers here:

1. Sanitizing the inputs for safety.
2. Normalizing the inputs for query patterns.

**DO NOT EVEN ATTEMPT #1**

Sanitizing inputs for SQL is a doomed task. The correct procedure is instead to ***quarantine*** those inputs to be separate from the SQL. The mechanism for accomplishing this is parameterized queries or prepared statements, depending on your platform of choice.

I bring this up, because the leading and trailing % wildcards should also be included as part of the SQL for these queries. This will also help by making part 2 a little easier.

Speaking of part 2, to start with, in Notepad++ you can do a simple find/replace for a space to put a `%` wildcard in it's place. A similar operation for punctuation is also easy. You can use the regex option to put commas, periods, etc in a single character class (`[,.;'/<>!@#$%^&*()]`), and replace that with an empty textbox.

Removing "Inc" and "LLC" with this tool is trickier. The main problem is they're probably not the only snippet you'll care about. LTD and AG come to mind as other options, and there are more. At some point you'll want a table for this, and that means computer code... Excel macro at a minimum.

Next up is making the text upper case. Instead, here I recommend you rely on the features of your database. By default, most database platforms are already case insensitive, and those that aren't can generally force a specific collation. That's what you should do for this.

We need to think out the `OR` conditions. The proposed solution is extremely inefficient. You can improve on this by using a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with a JOIN. I don't know what database platform you're using. The link is for Sql Server, but other databases have similar features. This will make building the list a little easier. Even better if you run your list as a series of INSERT statements into a holding table. Then you can JOIN to the table, with no special syntax needed.

Finally, I need to talk about the leading `%` wildcards. This is *absolute murder* for performance. If you want this query to complete in a reasonable amount of time, and you ever expect to run it, or anything similar, again, I strongly suggest looking into full-text index and the CONTAINS operator.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a notepad++ command to find and replace for the trailing "Inc" , "LTD" and "LLC" etc.,??